# How to auto update data in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-channels, django-signals

I am trying to build eCommerce application in Django. In each product I have three label tags which are **is_new**, **is_hot**, **is_promo**.

1. **is_new** will be **True** when a product will create, I have done it. But the system needs to automatically make **is_new** to **False** when a product is older than 7 days. I have added **created_date** field in **Product** model. How could I auto update **is_new** to False? Any hints?
2. **is_hot** will be **True** when a product will most sold. Actually the first two product will be hot. And when other product goes hot then previous hot products will be automatically **False**. How to do it? Hints?
3. **is_promo** will be **True** when I will add discount to a product. And it will be **False** when I will remove the discount. Any hints?

Comment: you can write the logic in the views.py itself. As in query for all the products which are 7 days old and add the logic to your home_view. So that whenever the home page is rendered it will do all the preprocessing and give appropriate results.

Comment: also, look into [@property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods) for the is_new, and is_promo attributes.

Comment: Hey same thing I have done. But it only work when i restart the server or save codebase. then it automatically updates the view. I think django has by default caching. I've tried generic view on home Listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you implement these depends on how you're handling the related data.

- `is_new` you need the creation date.
- `is_hot` you need related sold count and a value to compare it too, like hot_threshold_count or something.
- `is_promo` you probably want this linked to promotion details.

Here's a rough sketch on how I would handle this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings


class Product(models.Model):
    ...  # name, etc
    creation_datetime = models.Datetime(auto_add_now=True)
    sold_count = models.Integer(default=0)

    @property
    def is_hot(self) -> bool:
        return self.sold_count >= settings.HOT_COUNT_THRESHOLD

    @property
    def is_new(self) -> bool:
        elapsed_days = (timezone.now() - self.creation_datetime).days
        return elapsed_days <= settings.MAX_NEW_DAYS

    @property
    def is_promo(self) -> bool:
        has_promos = bool(Promotion.objects.filter(product=self).count())
        return has_promos



class Promotion(models.Model):
    creation_datetime = models.Datetime(auto_add_now=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    discount_percentage = models.Float()
```

> WHERE:
>   settings.MAX_NEW_DAYS is a timedelta object

Comment: After reading this, It takes just a couple of minutes to solve the problem.
Thanks.